# How to hide method of base class from being acessed by object of child class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

How can i stop x(an object of child class)  from acessing the method  show_catalogue() , of base class?
I want to make a base class , to store all the bike objects which are available for rent , and then want to make this catalogue an attribute of another class Rentshop? Is the way i am doing it is correct?

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np


class bike_shop:


    bike_list = [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "BikeName": "Bajaj CT 100",
            "Rent_hour": 139,
            "Rent_Weekly": 599,
            "Rent_Monthly": 3339
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "BikeName": "Bajaj CT 100",
            "Rent_hour": 139,
            "Rent_Weekly": 599,
            "Rent_Monthly": 3339
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "BikeName": "Bajaj CT 100",
            "Rent_hour": 139,
            "Rent_Weekly": 599,
            "Rent_Monthly": 3339
        },
        {
            "ID": 4,
            "BikeName": "Bajaj CT 100",
            "Rent_hour": 139,
            "Rent_Weekly": 599,
            "Rent_Monthly": 3339
        },
        {
            "ID": 5,
            "BikeName": "Bajaj CT 100",
            "Rent_hour": 139,
            "Rent_Weekly": 599,
            "Rent_Monthly": 3339
        }
    ]


    def show_catalogue(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(bike_shop.bike_list)
        return df





class Rentshop(bike_shop):
    def __init__(self):
        self.catalogue = bike_shop.show_catalogue(self)


x = Rentshop()
print(x.catalogue)

print(x.show_catalogue())
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you describe what kind of problems you are facing with this approach?

Comment: you see , print(x.catalogue) , print(x.show_catalogue()) , one is an attribute of child class , and another a method of base class , i do not want the method of base class to be available to object of child class? I want to show the catalogue only via attribute of child class.

Comment: Second  , i want to know , if there is any wrong in  this approach , i am trying to make a rent shop , which will rent bikes  , i am using bikeshop for bike objects , and rentshop for rent related functionality

Comment: The easiest way how to prevent the child class from accessing parent's properties is to not inherit from that class in first place. Have both classes separately and call its method, no inheritance is and attempts to prevent accessing the attributes is needed.

Comment: ok , you mean simply call the method of above class in below ,using name above class , and do not inherit from it

Comment: you should think on why I declare `show_catalogue` as a method and I use it as class method (by passing ``self`)